# Where this approximation comes from?

Tags: functional-analysis, complex-analysis, analysis, partial-differential-equations

Let $k \in \mathbb{R}^{3}$ be fixed and $w: \mathbb{R}^{3} \to [0,\infty)$ be a nonnegative, radial and compactly supported function. Let $\Delta$ denote the usual Laplacian operator on $\mathbb{R}^{3}$. I came across the following approximation: let $f \in L^{2}(\mathbb{R}^{3})$ be fixed. Then,
$$\frac{1}{2}\lim_{\epsilon \to 0^{+}}(-\Delta -4\pi^{2}|k|^{2}-i\epsilon)^{-1}w(x)f(x) \approx -\frac{1}{8\pi}\int_{\mathbb{R}^{3}}dy \frac{e^{2\pi i \langle k, (x-y)\rangle}}{|x-y|}w(y)f(y). $$
Could someone please help me understand where this approximation comes from, that is, what is being used to get such approximation? It seems some sort of Green's function, but I was not able to justify it myself.

Comment: hint: apply a Fourier transform to each side.

Comment: What is $p$? It has not been introduced.

Comment: It was supposed to be $k$. Fixed it!